# Consume Microsoft Cluster API using PowerBI

Tags: api, powerbi, powerquery, azure-machine-learning-service

Thanks for getting back to me.

Basically I subscribed to a Cluster API service (cortana analytics). This is the sample application as per Microsoft Machine Learning site

http://microsoftazuremachinelearning.azurewebsites.net/ClusterModel.aspx

As you could see there are 2 arguments to be passed on

Input

K

Where input could be 10;5;2,18;1;6,7;5;5,22;3;4,12;2;1,10;3;4 (each row is separated by semi colon)

And K is cluster number: 5 (for example)

So to consume this API I use PowerBI Edit Query,

So go to Get Data > More > Azure > Microsoft Data MarketPlace, I can see the list of APIs I subscribed to, one of them is the one I referred to in the link above.

So I load that as Function lets called it "Score"

Then I got energy table which I loaded in from a csv file, I want to cluster energy consumption into 5 clusters.

So my data layout is

Year   Energy

2001   6.28213

2002  14.12845

2003   5.55851

and so on, lets say I got 100 rows of the data.

So I tried to pass "6.28213;14.12845;5.55851", "5" to Score function but I dont know how to

1. Convert my table into records
2. pass 2 argument records and constant value 5 as K.

Hope this makes sense.

Please help! :)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a column of numbers into a semicolon delimited text, do this to your table:

1. Convert your Energy column is type text.
2. Add `[Energy]` after the name of your table, which gives you a list of the numbers.
3. Use [`Text.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt253358.aspx) to turn the list into a text value seperated by `;`

Here's a mashup that does that:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("NcjBCQAgDAPAXfKWYqKR7iLdfw1F8J63N9Q70bBCKQ5Ue6VbnEHl9L9xz2GniaoD", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Year = _t, Energy = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Energy", type text}}),
    Custom1 = #"Changed Type"[Energy],
    Custom2 = Text.Combine(Custom1, ";")
in
    Custom2
```

---

Once you have a function, you'll invoke it like `YourFunction(Custum2, 5)`

Comment: almost got it except I got another error  DataSource.Error: We couldn't parse OData response result.  Error: The property 'V7' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.CloudML.ScoreResult'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.

Comment: Glad to see you got the function call working :) I'd normally say to ask a new stack overflow question for this but I think this is an odata bug. Maybe send a frown? If that doesn't help try power bi forums? :)